# Do same DNA sequences lead to the same proteins in all organisms?

Tags: cell-biology, dna

I'm not a biologist, but I am curious about a particular question about DNA.

As I understand DNA encodes proteins using special sequences of nucleotides and cells decode these proteins from DNA during cell division. My question is whether all organisms on earth have the same "decoding scheme" for DNA? Meaning that given a particular nucleotide sequence, will all organisms produce the same protein or some organisms evolved a different "decoding apparatus" that will produce some different protein?

Comment: The decoding scheme that you refer to is called the **Genetic Code**. Your question is answered on this list [here.](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/43589/mitochondrial-genetic-code/43596#43596) Your understanding is incorrect in certain instances. It is mRNA — not DNA — that is decoded, and this occurs all the time, and not particularly at cell division. These latter aspects of your question are very basic, which is why you really need to read the relevant chapters on transcription and translation in a text book.

Comment: Aside from the genetic code itself, "post translational modification" can affect protein sequence and structure. Here's a brief overview: https://www.thermofisher.com/us/en/home/life-science/protein-biology/protein-biology-learning-center/protein-biology-resource-library/pierce-protein-methods/overview-post-translational-modification.html